# Remove Column from ParseInstallation

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to set undefined to a column called "user" on my Installation class. I don't get any error message but the column still with value. Why?

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
installation.remove("user");
installation.saveInBackground();
```

Comment: Add `com.parse.SaveCallback callback` and see if you get any exception.

Comment: I changed the code to:                                 try {
                                    installation.save();
                                } catch (ParseException e1) {
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }

Comment: @tibo I'm not receiving error :(

Comment: actually, I meant: `public final void saveInBackground(com.parse.SaveCallback callback)`